# Response's 'respectfulness'

Tags: email

I'm in a work environment, and when a superior emails me to 'let me know' of something (e.g., Dear Bob, I'll be absent of the Tuesday meeting because of x.) I don't know what response has a proper tone.

My thoughts are that:
"Got it, thank you.",
"Message received, thank you.", and
"Ok, thanks!",
sound like things a superior would be responding me (rather than the other way around).

I think that even thought phrases 'respectfulness' might vary with people's opinions, there is a standard. (A soldier doesn't go around telling his superiors "Ok" or "got it.")

Thus, my question is two-fold:

For practical reasons,

1) what response would be proper for a superior, but not so much that it sounds obsequious - or that you're a sycophant.

And for pedagogical reasons,

2) what is the area (and proper terminology) of linguistics which studies the language's 'properness'/'respectfulness'. (I assume this to be an area since 'properness' is ever evolving with society).

Comment: You might like to check out http://workplace.stackexchange.com/. Regarding your final question, this could be classed as "etiquette".

Comment: @nxx - Thanks! Didn't know that site existed.

Comment: For all those interested, I've asked this question in workplace.stackexchange.com; with the title "Response's 'respectfulness'/etiquette for an email that does not ask for a reply"

Answer (score 1):

Formal template:

> Dear Bob,
>   Yours of the 21st is at hand, concerning your planned absence from work on Friday the 26th. Please accept the heartfelt wishes for a safe and happy day off from
>   Your most humble servant,
>   [signature]

Less formal template:

> OK.
>   [no signature]

Answer (score 1):

This is quite possibly a question of personal preferences....... My personal preference for replying to these informative emails is to simply reply with:

> Thanks for letting me know.

If circumstances warrant it, I might add a

> I hope you get well soon / Enjoy your game of golf / I will forward you the minutes of the meeting.

I sign off with my standard email signature.